# Automatically rebuilding dependency files generated with -MMD after deleting them

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, g++

I have gotten tired of waiting for our builds to make dependency files separately from the object files so am trying to switch our build to use -MMD to make the .d files when it builds the .o files.

This works great and cut our build time in half, however because I have no rule to make a .d file, if they do not exist make ignores them and does not rebuild the object file.  One of our requirements is if the dependency files do not exist we rebuild them and apparently we do not like the "don't delete the dependency file" solution.  So, yes, we are looking at the situation where you build the baseline successfully and then in a fit of rage go about randomly deleting dependency files and are too lazy to do a make clean.

How can I tell make to just rebuild the .o file if the .d file does not exist?  When I make the .d dependent on the .o, I get "no rule to make target xyz.d".

Comment: So make a rule to generate the .d file.  Some make programs are smart enough to reload includes in the makefile after the .d has been changed.

Comment: The .d file gets made as a byproduct of the .o file with the -MMD flag.  If I make them separately then I double the compile time because it has to make the .d file and then the .o file.

Comment: We use "gcc -M *.cpp > .depend" then "include .depend"

Comment: That is building the dependency files in a separate step from  building the object files and thus doubles the compile time.  The point of using -MMD is to build both in one step.

Comment: The compiler steps are (1) C preprocessor (2) compiler (3) optimizer where steps 2 & 3 take all the time.  gcc -M only does step 1.

Comment: Our full build takes more than 45 minutes and a significant portion of that time is spent just building dependencies.  When a build only takes 5 minutes, you can waste a minute or two building dependencies separately.  At 45 minutes, those 10-20 minutes of dependency building make a big difference.  Additionally, when I change a header file, it builds all the dependency files for every single source file that uses it and THEN starts compiling.  This means that if there is an error it builds all the dependency files BEFORE the compile fails.  I spend much less time compiling using one -MMD.

Comment: Some makes have a way to say one rule makes 2 files.  With original make it was like "foo.o foo.d : foo.cpp"

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want to do.  I tried "%.o %.d : %.cpp", but it tried to run "gcc -o foo.d ....", which is obviously not what I want it to do.

Comment: I changed my $@ to $*.o and that rule looks like it is doing what I want it to do.  If you answer the question, I'll accept it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it :

```make
EXE := toto
SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
DIR := obj
OBJ := $(SRC:%.cpp=$(DIR)/%.o)
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ) $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

$(DIR)/%.o $(DIR)/%.d: %.cpp | $(DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $*.o -c $<

$(DIR):
    @mkdir $@

-include $(DEPS)

clean:
    @$(RM) -r $(DIR)

fclean: clean
    @$(RM) $(EXE)

re: fclean all
```

When I manually delete one of the `.d` files and run `make`, it is rebuilt.
The only thing is that the executable is also rebuilt.